# Stackoverflow exception occurs while trying to get all combinations from two arrays

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all combinations from `int[] prices` and `int[] volumes`. The two arrays are of the same size each item in prices have an analogous volume in volumes, I want to create list of lists to represent a collection of size (`numberOfItemsInCollection`) and the sum of prices and volumes for each collection. each collection must be like the following (`item1, item2,.., item(n), sumPrices, sumVolumes`) so that I can use the sums in further calculations and comparisons.

I used the code like the following and a stack over flow exception occurs

```
public static void Permute(int[] prices, int[] volumes, int numberOfItemsInCollection, int k, List<int> curr, int sumPrice, int sumVolume,List<List<int>> ans)
{
    if (curr.Count == numberOfItemsInCollection)
    {
        curr.Add(sumPrice);
        curr.Add(sumVolume);
        ans.Add(new List<int>(curr));
        sumPrice = 0;
        sumVolume = 0;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = k; i < prices.Length; i++)
    {
        curr.Add(prices[i]);
        sumPrice+=prices[i];
        sumPrice+=volumes[i];
        Permute(prices, volumes, numberOfItemsInCollection, i, curr,sumPrice, sumVolume, ans);
        curr.RemoveAt(curr.Count - 1);
    }
}

public static List<List<int>> Permute(int[] prices, int[] volumes, int numberOfItemsInCollection)
{
    List<List<int>> ans = new List<List<int>>();
    Permute(prices, volumes, numberOfItemsInCollection, 0, new List<int>(),0,0, ans);
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: stack overflow is likely an infinite recursion.

Comment: ok how to solve this problem

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: I tried debugging and tried a lot of solutions but neither worked

Comment: solve = stop recursing infinitely. Debug your code,  see where it's going wrong.

Comment: _"ok how to solve this problem"_  By debugging and fixing your code.

Comment: If you want _our_ help to debug your code, give some valid inputs, and the expected output

Comment: I can tell you this line looks suspect `sumPrice+=volumes[i];` although not related to the infinite recursion. The other thing is you either need to start your loop at `k+1` or pass `i+1` to the recursive call. Not sure which gives you the answer you expect because I cant follow what you;re trying to get.

Comment: You're never calling your overload of `Permute` (the second method), you just keep calling the first method which is bound to cause a `StackoverflowException`.

Comment: With a couple of breakpoints and simple debugging, you should quickly see somewhere that the inputs are not expected. Recursion is quite specialist but also quite easy to debug. You might also have a problem if the arrays are very large, since even if the code is valid, there is a default limit of around 1MB for the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion should halt when `curr.Count == numberOfItemsInCollection`. As far as I can tell `curr.Count` should increase by one for each level in the recursion tree, i.e. it should be equal to the recursion depth. So the maximum recursion depth should be equal to `numberOfItemsInCollection`.

So as far as i can see this is a case of infinite recursion. I would estimate one stack frame to take about 60 bytes, so with a 4Mb stack size you should fit about 50k stack frames. So a important question is, how large is `numberOfItemsInCollection` ? If it is larger than around 1k it might be better to rewrite your algorithm to use iteration with an explicit stack rather than using recursion.

A good way to find out the problem yourself is to debug your program. Eric Lippert has a good article on [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Debugging recursion errors can be a little bit more complicated, but I think visual studio has fairly good tools that should allow you to check if parameters change for each call in a way that should reach the terminating condition.

You might also consider replacing your `List<int> curr` parameter with a [stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-6.0), since it seem to be used that way.